# Getting image is not saving to project directory

Tags: spring-mvc

My folder structure is `webapp-->resource--> images`.

Here is my code:

```
public String addProductPost(@ModelAttribute("products") Product product, HttpServletRequest request) {

        productDao.addProduct(product);
        System.out.println(product);

        MultipartFile productImage = product.getProductImage();
        String rootDirectory = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
        path = Paths.get(rootDirectory +"webapp/resources/image"+ product.getProductId()+".png");

        if (productImage !=null && !productImage.isEmpty()) {

            try {
                productImage.transferTo(new File(path.toString()));
                /*Files.copy(Paths.get(productImage.toString()), path);*/
            }  catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException("Product image saving failed ", e);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What happens when the `try{}` is run currently? Do you get an exception?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `System.out.println(path);` ? If you're not getting any error then the image is getting saved in the said directory but doesn't show up in eclipse project manager. To see the image, navigate to the folder where you have said the image.

Comment: I am getting following error but upto path its showing directory , next to that its not saving into my project directory webapp/resource/images          java.io.FileNotFoundException: F:\My music Web application\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\MusicStore\webapp\resources\image\92.png (The system cannot find the path specified)

Comment: Did you add the multipart bean in Web.xml ? Is the image folder existing in resouces folder? Did you manually go to the F:\ path and check if image exists there or not?